# Why does the training time increase so much during the first epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have 20 tfrecords files with a size of 2.6 Gb each, there are about 28000 images in each file. When I run the model (efficientnet), I notice a strange behavior during the first epoch, it increases sharply and goes to a constant value. Most likely there is some kind of I/O problem, but I can't figure out exactly where. Do you have any ideas? Tensorflow version 2.5.1, A100 graphics card.

The logs look like this:

```
Epoch 00001: LearningRateScheduler reducing learning rate to 0.0001.

   1/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 22:45:34 - loss: 0.7033 - auc: 0.5162
   2/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:41 - loss: 0.6990 - auc: 0.5275    
   3/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:05 - loss: 0.7042 - auc: 0.5031
   4/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:14 - loss: 0.6990 - auc: 0.5250
   5/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:17 - loss: 0.7016 - auc: 0.5161
   6/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:09 - loss: 0.7005 - auc: 0.5208
   7/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:11 - loss: 0.7035 - auc: 0.5117
   8/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:13 - loss: 0.7034 - auc: 0.5090
   9/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:14 - loss: 0.7008 - auc: 0.5147
  10/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:09 - loss: 0.7022 - auc: 0.5086
  11/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:05 - loss: 0.7021 - auc: 0.5090
  12/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:56 - loss: 0.7039 - auc: 0.5045 
  13/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:59 - loss: 0.7037 - auc: 0.5054
  14/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:59 - loss: 0.7052 - auc: 0.5023
  15/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:56 - loss: 0.7045 - auc: 0.5063
  16/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:57 - loss: 0.7028 - auc: 0.5108
  17/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:58 - loss: 0.7007 - auc: 0.5172
  18/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:56 - loss: 0.7009 - auc: 0.5157
  19/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:55 - loss: 0.6996 - auc: 0.5209
  20/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:51 - loss: 0.6995 - auc: 0.5193
  21/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 9:50 - loss: 0.6995 - auc: 0.5191
  22/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 10:45 - loss: 0.6994 - auc: 0.5185
  23/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 11:33 - loss: 0.6986 - auc: 0.5224
  24/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 12:20 - loss: 0.7006 - auc: 0.5166
  25/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 12:59 - loss: 0.6995 - auc: 0.5214
  26/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 13:34 - loss: 0.6987 - auc: 0.5238
  27/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 14:06 - loss: 0.6986 - auc: 0.5236
  28/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 14:36 - loss: 0.6990 - auc: 0.5215
  29/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 15:05 - loss: 0.6992 - auc: 0.5227
  30/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 15:31 - loss: 0.6986 - auc: 0.5250
  31/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 15:58 - loss: 0.6980 - auc: 0.5274
  32/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 16:23 - loss: 0.6971 - auc: 0.5312
  33/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 16:46 - loss: 0.6968 - auc: 0.5325
  34/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 17:08 - loss: 0.6955 - auc: 0.5376
  35/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 17:30 - loss: 0.6967 - auc: 0.5339
  36/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 17:48 - loss: 0.6968 - auc: 0.5332
  37/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 18:05 - loss: 0.6974 - auc: 0.5310
  38/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 18:22 - loss: 0.6973 - auc: 0.5305
  39/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 18:37 - loss: 0.6971 - auc: 0.5329
  40/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 18:51 - loss: 0.6977 - auc: 0.5304
  41/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 19:04 - loss: 0.6973 - auc: 0.5323
  42/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 19:17 - loss: 0.6970 - auc: 0.5343
  43/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 19:29 - loss: 0.6975 - auc: 0.5321
  44/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 19:41 - loss: 0.6970 - auc: 0.5338
  45/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 19:52 - loss: 0.6964 - auc: 0.5361
  46/1750 [..............................] - ETA: 20:02 - loss: 0.6963 - auc: 0.5355
```

Functions that are responsible for data preparation:

```
def get_dataset(files, batch_size=16, repeat=False, shuffle=False, aug=True, labeled=True, return_image_ids=True):
    ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files, num_parallel_reads=AUTO, compression_type="GZIP")
    ds = ds.prefetch(AUTO)
    ds = ds.cache()

    if repeat:
        ds = ds.repeat()

    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(1024 * 2)
        opt = tf.data.Options()
        opt.experimental_deterministic = False
        ds = ds.with_options(opt)

    if labeled:
        ds = ds.map(read_labeled_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    else:
        ds = ds.map(lambda example: read_unlabeled_tfrecord(example, return_image_ids), num_parallel_calls=AUTO)

    ds = ds.batch(batch_size * REPLICAS)
    if aug:
        ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: aug_f(x, y, batch_size * REPLICAS), num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    ds = ds.prefetch(AUTO)
    return ds

def prepare_image(wave, dim=256):
        with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
            wave = tf.reshape(tf.io.decode_raw(wave, tf.float64), (3, 4096))
            normalized_waves = []
            for i in range(3):
                normalized_wave = wave[i] / tf.math.reduce_max(wave[i])
                normalized_waves.append(normalized_wave)
            wave = tf.stack(normalized_waves)
            wave = tf.cast(wave, tf.float32)
            image = create_cqt_image(wave, HOP_LENGTH)
            image = tf.image.resize(image, size=(dim, dim))
        return tf.reshape(image, (dim, dim, 3))

def create_cqt_image(wave, hop_length=16):
    CQTs = []
    for i in range(3):
        x = wave[i]
        x = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(x, 0), 2)
        x = tf.pad(x, PADDING, "REFLECT")

        CQT_real = tf.nn.conv1d(x, CQT_KERNELS_REAL, stride=hop_length, padding="VALID")
        CQT_imag = -tf.nn.conv1d(x, CQT_KERNELS_IMAG, stride=hop_length, padding="VALID")
        CQT_real *= tf.math.sqrt(LENGTHS)
        CQT_imag *= tf.math.sqrt(LENGTHS)

        CQT = tf.math.sqrt(tf.pow(CQT_real, 2) + tf.pow(CQT_imag, 2))
        CQTs.append(CQT[0])
    return tf.stack(CQTs, axis=2)

def read_labeled_tfrecord(example):
    tfrec_format = {
        "wave": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "wave_id": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "target": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrec_format)
    return prepare_image(example["wave"], IMAGE_SIZE), tf.reshape(tf.cast(example["target"], tf.float32), [1])


def read_unlabeled_tfrecord(example, return_image_id):
    tfrec_format = {
        "wave": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "wave_id": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, tfrec_format)
    return prepare_image(example["wave"], IMAGE_SIZE), example["wave_id"] if return_image_id else 0
```

Model Training:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = build_model(
    size=IMAGE_SIZE, 
    efficientnet_size=EFFICIENTNET_SIZE,
    weights=WEIGHTS, 
    count=train_image_count // BATCH_SIZE // REPLICAS // 4)


history = model.fit(
    get_dataset(files_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, repeat=True, aug=True),
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[model_ckpt, get_lr_callback(BATCH_SIZE, REPLICAS)],
    steps_per_epoch=train_image_count // BATCH_SIZE // REPLICAS // 4,
    validation_data=get_dataset(files_valid, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE * 4, repeat=False, shuffle=False, aug=False),
    verbose=1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a lack of RAM. When using caching, my dataset needed about 64 GB of memory.